# Как умножить EditText на 3 TextView и разделить на 100

Tags: java, android

Я скачал приложение с рецептами. Я туда хочу добавлять свои рецепты которые проверил, как и на сколько они поднимают сахар.

Я добавляю рецепт и указываю на сколько поднялся сахар в крови когда я сьел 100 грамм этого продукта. Чтобы не считать эти все углеводы, хлебные единицы и калории...

Вот само приложение: prowebber_ru/internet/i-scripts/23428-your-recipes-app-v250-prilozhenie-receptov-android.html

Все получается, и новые поля добавил нашел news_date в файлах админ панели и в приложении и просто копировал и изменял на другие значения, все класcно работает, были ошибки но сейчас их вроде нет. Рецепты добавляються и в приложении появляются.

Я создал три поля которые вытягиваются с базы SQLLite в файле activity_recipes_detail.xml

```
(TextView - @+id/date) news_date - это на сколько поднялся сахар (12)
(TextView - @+id/insulin) news_insulin - сколько уколол инсулина (4)
(TextView - @+id/uglevodi) news_uglevodi - сколько углеводов на 100 грамм (48)
```

Я хочу ввести количество грамм сколько я хочу сьесть в `(EditText - @+id/porc)` и чтобы в 3-х TextView значения поменялись на новые с учетом умноженного и разделенного...
Таким образом, я буду знать, что если я сьем 300 грамм торта такой же марки как и в прошлый раз, то он поднимит мне сахар на столько то.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В xml на кнопке, которую нажимаешь после ввода значения в Edit, добавляешь

```
android:onClick="MyFunc"
```

В код добавляешь свою функцию расчета

```
public void MyFunc(View view) {
// тут расчет X, Y, Z
// находим поля для ввода
TextView date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
TextView insulin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.insulin);
TextView uglevodi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.uglevodi);
// заменяем текст
date.setText(String.valueOf(X));
insulin.setText(String.valueOf(Y));
uglevodi.setText(String.valueOf(Z));
}
```

Comment: DrMcSheen спасибо за помощь! В комментарии написано "// тут расчет X, Y, Z" не подскажите, как найти этот код расчета?

Comment: Простите, но я понятия не имею, как расчитываются даные о сахаре. Предполагаю, что нужно заполнять ещё одно поле с данными о продукте, ведь непонятно, когда Вы вводите "100" грамм, а 100 грамм ЧЕГО? Тут нужен бы выпадающий список продуктов, имеющихся в базе. Потом из базы берутся значения сахара, углеводов и - чего там ещё нужно, не знаю - и по этим данным расчитываюся результаты.